# Проблема с иконкой приложения Java

Tags: java, изображения, icon

Имеется приложения на **Java**. В приложении генерируется **иконка** и кладется рядом с приложением в папку **res** (имя иконки всегда одинаковое **tray.png** - т.е. она **перезаписывается**). Так вот когда приложение стартует, у него уже лежит какая-то иконка (например **черная**). Это изображение подгружается и **устанавливается**, дальше происходит **генерация** новой иконки (например **зеленой**), и снова устанавливается на иконку, соответственно должна произойти **замена** иконки с **черной** на **зеленую**, но этого **не происходит** (иконка обновляется, но снова на черную, которой уже в ресурсах нету в принципе).

Иконки сохраняю так:

```
ImageWriteEx ImageWriteEx = new ImageWriteEx();
BufferedImage bi = ImageWriteEx.createImageWithText();
File outputfile = new File("./res/tray.png");
ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
```

Иконки подгружаю так:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("./res/tray.png");
setIconImage(image);
```

Так вот, в чем у меня проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы предложил сначала загрузить картинку как ресурс используя `getResource` или `getResourceAsStream`:

```
// this здесь добавлен исключительно для наглядности
this.getClass().getResource("res/tray.png")
```

А дальше поискать метод который принимает картинку как InputStream или [ImageInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/ImageInputStream.html)

Comment: К сожалению, через getResource() у меня не ставится картинка вообще, но я вышел из положения так: не сохраняя никаких ресурсов, передаю напрямую переменную `bi`

Comment: Так даже лучше, если иконка сохранялась для того чтобы быть прочитанной.